# Is it possible to track sales conversion with only Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics? (no Google Ads access)

Tags: magento, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am working for a client to set up Google Ecommerce data for their Google Analytics.  I have done this once before on another site where I used a Google Ads conversion placed inside of a Google Tag that was placed on the site.  However, for this client, we don't have access to the Google Ads account; we only have access to the Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager.  Is there a way to set up a Google Tag that will capture the data we need from their sales?

I have attempted a few different methods I've seen on the other forums but after waiting a day in between them being set, we still have no data coming in.

**Details:**  We are using Magento 1.9 for the site and have access to the files to make modifications as needed to our custom theme.  The order page ends on a success page for the user that uses the URL ending portion as 'checkout/onepage/success'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can see the data you need by using Google Analytics API
for example, if you want to check how many transactions between two dates uses this code:

Reporting API V3:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids={ViewId}&start-date={StartDate}&end-date={EndDate}&metrics=ga:transactions
```

Reporting API V4:

```
{
  "reportRequests": [
    {
      "viewId": "XXXXXXX",
      "dateRanges": [
        {
          "startDate": "2021-01-01",
          "endDate": "2021-03-01"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": [
        {
          "expression": "ga:transactions"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Check this URL for all Dimensions & Metrics :
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/

Comment: Thank you for responding!  Is there an alternative way to get this data through the use of Google Tag configuration instead?  I can see that our data arrays are being produced when an order has been made, but I tried using ecommerce.products.price methods.  However, I'm not sure if that is the right way to access the data from the data layer in Google tag Manager.

Answer (score 0):

For those that come across this issue you can do it with the following:

1. Set up a Google Analytics variable that holds the value for your google analytics
2. Under Ecommerce (inside GA variable) enable enhanced ecommerce features and use the data layer
3. Create a trigger that is set to page view with the URL that contains the success page (or order completed page)
4. Create a Tag with the Universal GA
5. Use the GA variable, set the track type to Transaction
6. Publish and wait to see the information on the following day.

Link from Google that describes the process for set up:
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169